# Seprate string to rows

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Heyy guys i am using 11g ... i have data like below one

```
col1
email@id
```

and my output should look like

```
col1
e
m
a
i
l
@
i
d
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: You can achieve that easily with a *numbers/digits/tally* table and `substring()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use connect by to achieve your desired result:

Schema:

```
         create table table1 (col1 varchar2(100));   
         insert into table1 values('email@id');
```

Query:

```
         select  substr(col1, level, 1) col1
         from table1
         connect by level <= length(col1) ;
```

Output:

```
     | COL1 |
     |------|
     | e    |
     | m    |
     | a    |
     | i    |
     | l    |
     | @    |
     | i    |
     | d    |
```

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8bb6d49e3dcc720123dd61552e5b2449)*

Comment: Run `insert into table1 values('another_email@id');` and then run your query again. What happens?

Answer (score 0):

With sample table's contents as

```
SQL> select * from table1;

COL1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
email@id
LittleFoot
```

you'd

```
SQL> select substr(col1, column_value, 1) val
  2  from table1 cross join
  3    table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  4                        connect by level <= length(col1)
  5                       ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
  6  order by col1, column_value;

VAL
----
e
m
a
i
l
@
i
d
L
i
t
t
l
e
F
o
o
t

18 rows selected.

SQL>
```